# Basic C++ question about constructors of two classes that are very similar

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, attributes, encapsulation

This is a relatively easy question about constructors in C++. Suppose I have a class A representing a 3D collection of velocity vectors (that are also a class for some reasons). My class A is defined by the following (I took off the methods):

```
class A {
public:
A(int Nx, int Ny, int Nz, double lambda) 
: field(Nx, vector<vector<Velocity>>(Ny, vector<Velocity>(Nz))), Nx(Nx), Ny(Ny), Nz(Nz), lambda(lambda)
{}

private:
vector<vector<vector<Velocity>>> field;
double Nx;
double Ny;
double Nz;
double lambda;
};
```

Now suppose I have a class B that is also a 3D collection but of force vectors this time, we would like to create a constructor that receives a `field` as a parameter and initializes its "3D matrix" to the same sizes as the of the `field` it receives.

```
class B {
public:
B(const A& sky) 
: space( ??? ) //How can I give space the informations that are private in A without getters methods ?
{}

private:
vector<vector<vector<Force>>> space;
double Nx;
double Ny;
double Nz;
double lambda;
};
```

My question is the following : how can I give the attribute "space" the informations that are private in A without getters methods to have a space with the same size of the field for example if the field of the class A has been initialized with sizes 30x30x30 and lambda = 2, how can I give them to the "space" attribute of class B without creating a method that gives access to the private attributs of  class A and calling it in the constructor of class B I'm struggling to build, the method would look like this :

```
vector<double> A::getters() const {
    vector<double> bad_habit ({Nx, Ny, Nz, lambda});
    return bad_habit;
}
```

(Since A and B are both 3D collections, I thought of creating a superclass named 3D Collection, I don't know if it can be useful to solve the problem or if it just makes things harder)

Comment: It can be disturbing if it modifies A a lot and impacts the methods I didn't show but yes why not, I'll learn something new, go on ! @cigien

Comment: I read this a few times, and am struggling to understand what you really want. It sounds like you're asking how to provide access to something whilst providing no access to the same thing. You have a thick collection of collections (of collections) that you want to reference/copy, but don't want to provide any means to do so? `A` and `B` are unrelated classes. Your only access is that which you programmatically provide, be it by friending, by accessor, or otherwise.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry if what I'm asking is not clear, I'm new to oop and coding. Without details, I would say that the question can be summarized as "How can I give to an object of class B the same attributes of class A without creating getters  ?"

Comment: As unrelated classes, there are few options. (1) make the members public (yuck). (2) `friend` class `A` to `B` (not so yuck). (3) Provide a filler in A that takes a `B&` and fills what you're asking for (likely requires friending `B` to `A`, back to yuck), and lastly (4) Provide actual public getters and keep your members private. I strongly discourage (1) and (3), and suggest you choose the lesser of two evils of (2) and (4).

Answer (score 0):

As answered by WhozCraig in the comments:

As unrelated classes, there are few options.
(1) make the members public (yuck).
(2) friend class A to B (not so yuck).
(3) Provide a filler in A that takes a B& and fills what you're asking for (likely requires friending B to A, back to yuck), and lastly
(4) Provide actual public getters and keep your members private.

I strongly discourage (1) and (3), and suggest you choose the lesser of two evils of (2) and (4).